# useEffect not re-rendering after state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a little side project to get more familiar with Hooks and I am running into a problem right now:

The project is a weather app, pulling weather data for a city from an API. The code below is a simplified version of the app. \

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState<any>({})
    const [city, setCity] = useState<string>("London")
    const [cities, setCities] = useState<string[]>([
        "London",
        "New York",
        "Dubai",
        "Berlin",
        "Los Angeles",
        "Sydney",
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://api-url/?query=${city}`)
            .then(res => setWeather(res.data))
            .catch ...
    }, [])

    return (
        <Drawer>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    {cities.map((c, i) => (
                        <li key={i} onClick={() => setCity(c)}>
                            {c}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </Drawer>
        // more JSX to display weather data for current city
    )
}
```

**Expected behaviour:** 
Clicking on `li` elements sets the state of `city` to the new city and rerenders the UI, loading the weather data for the selected city.

**Actual behavour:**
State gets set, but app doesn't reload the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `city` as the dependency, telling when to re-execute the effect.

See [Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) for more details about the `[]` argument.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://api-url/?query=${city}`)
        .then(res => setWeather(res.data))
        .catch ...
}, [city])
```

Also see [ESLint plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) for Rules of Hooks and Exhaustive Deps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to pass in `cities`, which obviously didn't work. Passing `city` worked, thanks!

Comment: I added a link to the eslint plugin which will tell you next time  you miss a dependency :)